# Unable to list locks using list_at_resource_level in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-python

```
compute_client = authenticate.client_management(subscription_id)
for resource_group in resources_groups.keys():
    vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group)
for vm in vm_list:
    array = vm.id.split("/")
    locks_client = authenticate.locks_client(subscription_id)
    result = locks_client.management_locks.list_at_resource_level(resource_group, "Microsoft.Compute",
                                                                  "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/YYYY",
                                                                  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines", array[-1])
```

Using the following class for locks ::

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/resource/locks/v2016_09_01/operations/_management_locks_operations.py
```

The result of the above program is ::

```
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (InvalidResourceType) The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Compute' for api version '2016-09-01'.
Code: InvalidResourceType
```

Can someone please help me fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating `compute_client`? Please edit your question and include the code for that? Also mention the SDK version you are using?

Comment: As the azure.mgmt.resource.locks is in only 2015-01-01 & 2016-09-01, I'm unable to use virtualmachines resource type. So not exactly solved my problem, but gave me enough clarity. Thanks @VenkatesanSettu-MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError:(InvalidResourceType) The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Compute' for api version '2016-09-01'. Code: InvalidResourceType

The above error is usually occurs:

- API version not supported for the resource type.
- Location not supported for the resource type.
- The required resource provider hasn't been registered for your subscription.

The above used Api version is not supported in **resourcetypes** kindly check the below image has been provided listed of api version in it.

***Check and use the correct API Versions:***

[image]

***Locations:***

[image]

***Reference:***
**[View resource provider-MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#view-resource-provider)**